# sql query - Invalid column name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I get an error when I execute the following sql query.

```
SELECT 
    RTRIM(name) AS [Segment Name], 
    growth,groupid AS [Group Id], 
    filename AS [File   Name],
    CAST(size/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Size in MB],
    CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Space Used],
    CAST(size/128.0-(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Available Space],
    CAST((CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2))/CAST(size/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)))*100 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Percent_Used]
FROM 
    sysfiles
WHERE 
    growth = 0 AND  Percent_Used > 60
ORDER BY 
    groupid DESC
```

The error says:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Invalid column name 'Percent_Used'.

Why do I get this error??

Comment: I don't know well sql-server, but what about removing the underscore (as the columns aliases above seems to works fine)

Comment: See [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx): "because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses ... 4. WHERE ... 8. SELECT ..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you see logical order processing of query where clause is evaluated before select.
to make it work you need to use derived table concept.

```
1. FROM
2. ON
3. OUTER
4. **WHERE**
5. GROUP BY
6. CUBE | ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. **SELECT**
```

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/06/sql-server-logical-query-processing-phases-order-of-statement-execution/

```
   Select * from
    (
        SELECT 
            RTRIM(name) AS [Segment Name], 
            growth,groupid AS [Group Id], 
            filename AS [File   Name],
            CAST(size/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Size in MB],
            CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Space Used],
            CAST(size/128.0-(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Available Space],
            CAST((CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2))/CAST(size/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)))*100 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Percent_Used]
        FROM 
            sysfiles
    ) DT

        WHERE growth = 0 AND  Percent_Used > 60
        ORDER BY groupid DESC
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use a column you have defined to filter in the `WHERE` clause. This column does not exist in the table `sysfiles`

If you want you can wrap that `SELECT` in another `SELECT` and do the filtering on the latter `SELECT`. That way the column already "exists".

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte
AS
(
SELECT 
    RTRIM(name) AS [Segment Name], 
    growth,groupid AS [Group Id], 
    filename AS [File   Name],
    CAST(size/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Size in MB],
    CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Space Used],
    CAST(size/128.0-(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Available Space],
    CAST((CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed')/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2))/CAST(size/128.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2)))*100 AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS [Percent_Used]
FROM 
    sysfiles
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE 
    growth = 0 
    AND  Percent_Used > 60
ORDER BY [Group Id] DESC
```